# Uncaught TypeError after data is changed in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a bit of a weird error with react and my google charts, when i first login to my page that shows my chart everything shows fine, but theres a place where i import data for new values to show on my chart and the chart disappears when i import new values and i get the following errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: processedData[(index + 1)] is undefined
Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development
```

I have added null checks and everything but the error still persists.
Here is my code where the error is happening:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";

export const DoubleColumnChart = (props) => {

  const processData = (data) => {
    if (data == null) return [[]];
    if (data.labels == null) return [[]];
    var processedData = [[]];
    if(processData == null) return [[]];
    processedData[0].push('Category');
    data.labels.forEach(function (label) {
      var finalLabel = null;
      finalLabel = label[0];
      if (label.length > 1) {
        for (var i = 1; i < label.length; i++) {
          if (finalLabel.length > parseInt(160 / data.labels.length, 10)) {
            finalLabel = finalLabel + '...';
            break;
          }
          finalLabel = finalLabel + '\n' + label[i];
        }
      }
      processedData.push([finalLabel]);
    });
    
    data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
      processedData[0].push(dataset.label);
      dataset.data.forEach(function (data, index) {
        if(processData == null) return [[]];
        processedData[index + 1].push(data);
      });
    });

    return processedData;
  }

  const processColors = (data) => {
    if (data == null) return [];
    if (data.datasets == null) return [[]];
    var processedColors = [];
    data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
      processedColors.push(dataset.backgroundColor);
    });
    return processedColors
  }

  if (props.isVisible == false) {
    return <div></div>;
  }


  return (
    <Chart
      width={'99%'}
      height={'375px'}
      chartType="ColumnChart"
      loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
      data={processData(props.data)}
      options={{
        animation: {
          duration: 1500,
          easing: 'out',
          startup: true,
        },
        legend: { position: 'bottom', textStyle: { color: 'gray' } },
        vAxis: { textStyle: { color: 'gray' } },
        hAxis: { textStyle: { fontSize: 10, color: 'gray' } },
        tooltip: { trigger: 'hover', showColorCode: true },
        chartArea: {
          top: '2%',
          left: '5%',
          height: "77%",
          width: "100%",
        },
        colors: processColors(props.data),
        dataOpacity: '0.9',
      }}
      chartEvents={[
        {
          eventName: 'select',
          callback: ({ chartWrapper }) => {
            const chart = chartWrapper.getChart()
            const selection = chart.getSelection()
            if (selection.length === 1) {
              const [selectedItem] = selection;
              const { row } = selectedItem;
              var labelData = props.data.labels[row];
              var finalLabel = '';
              for (var i = 0; i < labelData.length; i++) {
                finalLabel = finalLabel + labelData[i];
              }
              finalLabel = finalLabel.replace(/ /g, '');
              if (props.onSegmentClick) props.onSegmentClick(finalLabel);
            }
          },
        },
      ]}
      rootProps={{ 'data-testid': '1' }}
    />
  );
}
```

But if i hard refresh, the new data does show and the console error goes away

Comment: Can you console.log the array and the index right before the error?

Comment: @Domino987 I can and it does show data, there is a lot of data which gets pulled through